# How to have Foreign Key Relation with a field that may contain Multiple Types of it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I am currently working on a DVD Store App. There are two tables in which I am having an issue. First is the **Genres** and the other is **DVDCatalog**. I need that DVD can be listed in one or more Genres. So, to do that I have to store like the IDs of the Genres (4,5,6). This way I can't make a relationship with the **GenresID** in the **Genres** Table. Do you have any solution for this, so that I can keep the relationship between them?

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Don't store the IDs of the Genres like `(4,5,6)` use [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and then you can get the referential integrity that you need.

You need a relationship table (say `DVD_Genres`) with 2 columns

`DVD_Id` and `Genre_Id` (These form the composite primary key)

Then if DVD Id 1 was in genres 4,5 and 6 you would have 3 rows in this table to represent this fact.

```
DVD_Id     Genre_Id
1            4
1            5
1            6
```

This also will make searching for DVDs matching a particular genre easier and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have created an "Association Table" containing fields DVD_Id and Genre_Id. And Yes this is more efficient way.